# How to fix "The current field `equivalents` is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ``"

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.8

I am modifying a Symfony 2.8 application that uses several Sonata bundles.

I have two entities: An old Page entity and a new Equivalent entity (which, in turn, contains two fields). Each Page can refer to multiple Equivalents, and each Equivalent can be referred to by multiple Pages, so I have set up a many-to-many mapping.

I generated an admin class for my Equivalent class using `sonata:admin:generate`, so I now have the following at the bottom of my admin.yml file:

```
app.admin.equivalent:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\EquivalentAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Equivalent, AppBundle:EquivalentAdmin]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Equivalent }
```

Editing Equivalent entities directly works well. Now I want to add inline editing of Equivalent entities from within my PageAdmin screen.

With that goal in mind, I add the following to PageAdmin.php:

```
            ->add('equivalents', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'label' => "Equivalents",
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'required' => false
            ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'targetEntity' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Equivalent',
            ))
```

So my question is:

**Why do I get a message saying** `The current field`equivalents`is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ""`**? What can I do to make the application recognize that it has an admin class available?**

(Most solutions I have seen for this type of problem have emphasized registering the new entity's admin class as a service, but it appears that my admin generation command already did that. I'm guessing that there's an additional line or two I'm missing somewhere, and that there will be a simple solution to my problem.)

Answer (score 0):

This didn't solve the problem entirely, but it helped: I added a true 'by_reference' value to my add() statement. So it now looks like:

```
            ->add('equivalents', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'label' => "Equivalents",
                'by_reference' => true, 
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'targetEntity' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Equivalent',
            ))
```

(This allowed me to move on to addressing a more useful error.)

====

**Edit:** It's also worth mentioning that adding a `'admin_code' => 'app.admin.equivalent'` value in the second array helped in a similar situation a few days later.

Comment: First: you don't need the target entity property, if your model and your admin is set up correct, it will automatically get all required information. Are you sure, every involved entity has an (correctly set up) admin class?